# how to know document created date in document library SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, document-library

How to know document created date in **Document Library** SharePoint 2010.

Here in columns of document library I see modified date only. In this document library there are many documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to list setting modify view.
- Select Created column.
- Click save.

You will be able to see created date as well.

It is OOTB column.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Modify View in the top ribbon. You will set of columns, Select the Created Date from the list of columns and click on Save. u can see the column now